A novel about an object from space crossing the solar system and found out not to be an asteroid but a spaceship. Not Greg Bear's Eon
I read this novel even before I read Eon by Greg Bear.
The common points is that an object arrives from space and though initially believed to be an asteroid it is found out it is in fact a spaceship. It contains very sophisticated technology, that humans are unable to understand, but the inventors of that technology are not in the ship anymore.
But there are important differences

the spaceship is large, but not larger inside than outside

it does not put itself in orbit, but leaves the solar system

IIRC there are robots that move on the ship



Sounds like Rendezvous With Rama, by Arthur C Clarke, a very early example of the Big Dumb Object sub-genre.
It contains all of the plot elements that you mention. It appears to be dormant when humans first arrive, but as it gets closer to the sun, robots emerge. It leaves the solar system again, but the last line left scope for sequels, which were written much later.

That was fast ! I went to the wiki page you posted the link to. And something clicked : things go by three. I had forgotten that detail, but it struck me as soon as I read the wiki page. Too early to accept, I'll do it in 2 minutes.

Really don't bother with the sequels though. (FWIW you may well find that RWR isn't worth a re-read either - a great concept turned into a truly boring book where nothing actually happens - but hey, YMMV.)

@Graham reading the book first time makes you feel the awe of finding an extraterrestrial civilization's artifact. That does not work when reading for the second time, maybe.

@Edheldil I'm afraid my reaction on first reading was "how can you take the awe of finding an extraterrestrial civilisation's artifact and make it tedious?!" I kept going, waiting for a pay-off, and it just never came. Clarke had great concepts, but he was never good at putting plots around them. I hoped that the sequels would add the depth that the original lacked, but they were truly awful.

The sequels are very... different. That said, I played the game (based on the second book) before reading the books, so I'm not unbiased, but I enjoyed the sequels. They do go downhill as the series "progresses", however, and Revealed in particular is much more a story about humans than anything else.

@Matthew et al - The sequels get a lot of negative reviews, but I suspect it's because people go into them expecting a "big concept" story, but they're actually much more character-focused with a touch of exploring alien civilizations.  They're a very different style of book from the original, so probably disappoint a lot of people who are fans of the original.

@Graham the sequels were embarrassingly bad indeed. I sort of liked Rama, even if it is a "low key" kind of book.
